# Calculating Probability of a given X range if X is a continuous random variable with a given PDF.

Tags: probability, statistics

This question was given to me as a review for an upcoming exam.

Find $P(2 \leq X \leq 3)$ if $X$ is a continous random variable with pdf:
$$f_X(x) =
 \begin{cases} 
      xe^{-x} & x\geq 0 \\
      0 & x \lt 0
   \end{cases}
$$
My work:
$$P(2 \leq X \leq 3) = \int_{2}^{3}xe^{-x}dx$$

Integration by parts:

$u=x,u'=1,v'=e^{-x},v=-e^{-x}$

$$\int_{2}^{3}xe^{-x} dx = -xe^{-x}\Big|^3_2-\int_{2}^{3}-e^{-x}dx\\
=\frac{-4}{e^3} + \frac{3}{e^2} \approx 0.2069$$

Did I miss anything or do something incorrectly?

---

Also, I had a quick question regarding a different case, let's say problem was asking for $P(-1 \leq X \leq 3)$ instead, would we do this instead?:
$$P(-1 \leq X \leq 3)= \int_{-1}^{0}0 dx + \int_0^3xe^{-x}dx$$

Obviously the left integral will be 0 in this case, I'm just wondering if we split up the integrals with addition if the range we are looking for is in two different domains of the PDF.

Comment: To your quick question -- yes

Comment: Both parts are correct.

Comment: Perhaps see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution). This is the PDF of a RV with dist'n $\mathsf{Gamma}(shape=2, rate=1).$ In R: code `diff(pgamma(c(2,3), 2, 1))` returns 0.2068576. Also, `pgamma(3, 2, 1)` returns 0.8008517. [`pgamma` is the CDF of a gamma distribution.] Because the support is the positive half line, you could just find $P(0 \le X \le 3).$